# Is there a fast way to get the tokens for each sentence in spaCy?

Tags: spacy

To split my sentence into tokens I'm doing the following whichi is slow

```
 import spacy nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

 text = "This is a test. This is another test"

 sentence_tokens = []
 doc = nlp(text) 
 for sent in doc.sents:
     words = nlp(sent.text)
     all = []
     for w in words:
         all.append(w)
         sentence_tokens.append(all)
```

I kind of want to do this the way nltk handles it where you split the text into sentences using `sent_tokenize()` and then for each sentence run `word_tokenize()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The main problem with your approach is that you're processing everything *twice*. A sentence in `doc.sents` is a [`Span`](https://spacy.io/api/span) object, i.e. a sequence of `Token`s. So there's no need to call `nlp` on the sentence text again – spaCy already does all of this for you under the hood and the `Doc` you get back already includes all information you need.

So if you need a list of strings, one for each token, you can do:

```py
sentence_tokens = []
for sent in doc.sents:
    sentence_tokens.append([token.text for token in sent])
```

Or even shorter:

```py
sentence_tokens = [[token.text for token in sent] for sent in doc.sents]
```

If you're processing a lot of texts, you probably also want to use `nlp.pipe` to make it more efficient. This will process the texts in batches and yield `Doc` objects. You can read more about it [here](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#processing).

```py
texts = ["Some text", "Lots and lots of texts"]
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts):
   sentence_tokens = [[token.text for token in sent] for sent in doc.sents]
   # do something with the tokens
```

Answer (score 4):

To just do the rule-based tokenization, which is very fast, run:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') # no need for large model
doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
print([token.text for token in doc])
```

There won't be sentence boundaries, though. For that you still currently need the parser. If you want tokens and sentence boundaries:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["tagger", "ner"]) # just the parser
doc = nlp(text)
print([token.text for token in doc])
print([sent.text for sent in doc.sents])
```

If you have a lot of texts, run `nlp.tokenizer.pipe(texts)` (similar to `make_doc()`) or `nlp.pipe(texts)`.

(Once you've run `doc = nlp(text)`, you don't need to run it again on the sentences within the loop. All the annotation should be there and you'll just be duplicating annotation. That would be particularly slow.)